How can I improve model accuracy?
Trying to work on a very basic model - here's how the database looks like:

and I tried to build a model that can predict the genre. No matter how I change the layers, batch size, I get an accuracy of 0.2~0.3.
Is there a better way I can modify the data or should I look for another database?
df['Top Genre'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df['Top Genre'])

numeric_features = ['Beats Per Minute (BPM)', 'Energy', 'Danceability', 'Loudness (dB)',
                    'Liveness', 'Valence', 'Length (Duration)', 'Acousticness', 'Speechiness', 'Popularity']

X = df[numeric_features]
y = df['Top Genre']

min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_scale = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scale, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[2],)),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(len(label_encoder.classes_), activation='softmax') 
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)

hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[early_stopping])

evaluation = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)```


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/vjkBl.png

